# access a partial's form_for(@variable) from any page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just finished Hartl's RoR tutorial and am now trying to mess around with some more stuff.

Specifically: I'm trying to allow the user to create microposts on any page, by rendering the micropost partial in the `header.html.erb` file (which is rendered on every page).

the partial:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "micropost" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Doing this has resulted in the error on line #1 of the partial: `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class` on any page which I have not fixed by adding `@micropost = current_user.microposts.build` in the controller method that links to said view. For example:

```
#in controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
def about
  if signed_in?
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
  end
end
```

Would fix this error when I visit the `about` page

I've been trying to figure out a way to do a "blanket fix" that will work on all pages without me having to paste in the declaration everywhere, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the `form_for` builder here; Rails also provides a `form_tag` helper for more generic forms:

```
<%= form_tag create_micropost_path, method: :post do %>
  <%= text_area_tag :micropost_content, placeholder: "micropost" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This way, you don't need to build the object when loading every page, but `microposts#create` can still pull data from `params[:micropost]`. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have SessionController, is created as follow guide in Tutorial, so you can make a helper method in SessionController, example:

```
def post_micropost
  if signed_in?
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
  end
end
```

Then, in your StaticsController, add a `before_filter` at the top of controller:

```
before_filter :post_micropost
```

So, in any action of StaticPagesController, user can post micropost also if they are signed in.

Comment: by StaticsController do you mean the static_pages_controller?

Comment: I have a few problems with this. Why would it go in SessionController? It's also going to create issues in other controller actions that _do_ need to instantiate a `@micropost` object.

Comment: @pseudosudo, yes, I means static_pages_controller, sorry :)

Comment: @ZachKemp What issues can created? You can control which actions in controller will use `post_micropost`. Because in Tutorial, the author created SessionsController to deal with actions need user signed in, so the OP can put in it for easy understand.

Comment: My understanding is that this form is to be rendered in the header, i.e. repeated on every page (not just in certain controllers). If I were to add to a controller, it would only be ApplicationController. The issues would come up if there were other actions that include an `@micropost` object, like `microposts#edit`, etc. If it was my app, I would feel the behavior was clearer if the forms were kept compartmentalized: one to receive simple post data to appear on every page like a widget, and one to create and edit explicit objects. I guess it's a matter of preference.

Comment: @ZachKemp All of your assumptions are correct, I was also planning on doing micropost edits after I figured this out

Comment: @ZachKemp okay, i understood what OP want to do. Thanks for explain and a suggest approach, I will remember it if in future I need to  build something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this before the form

```
<% @micropost ||= current_user.microposts.new %>
```

Comment: Worked magically for me. 
I realize this is probably "wrong" since we are embedding @micropost into the view but it just worked flawlessly